# Why do I get decimals when I use the substr function to get the first six characters in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataframe looks like this:

[image]

I have used the following function to extract the first 6 numbers of the `hs10` variable:

```
us_chn_tariffs_18$HS6 <- as.numeric(substr(as.character(us_chn_tariffs_18$hs10), 1, 6))
```

However, some variables have shown up with decimals as can be seen below:

[image]

Is there a reason for this, and how can I just get whole numbers?

Thank you.

Comment: what has happened on line 1412?

Answer (score 1):

When converting to character you are keeping the "e" from scientific notation, it happens only in some numbers for the quantity of 0's,6 or more 0's are converted to scientific notation.

```
substr(format(h10, scientific=F), 1,6)
```

That should work fine (at least in my R session it works just fine) hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to divide and `trunc`ate.

```
trunc(x/1e4)
# [1] 284699 284699 284700
```

or

```
as.character(trunc(x/1e4))
# [1] "284699" "284699" "284700"
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- 2846999998:2847000000
```

Comment: Thanks  - this worked, however I also got some results that were only 5 characters long even though the original hs10 observation was 10 characters long